# How to persist jsonwebtoken on page reload after deploying react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

I have this code in my index page of my react app:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import Router from './routes'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import setAuthorizationToken from './utils/setAuthorizationToken'
import {setCurrentUser} from './actions/loginActions'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f))


if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
    setAuthorizationToken(localStorage.jwtToken)
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwt.decode(localStorage.jwtToken)))
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The underlying idea is to use tokens as a form of authenticating client requests on the server. As such, every request from the client must have a token in the header which the server will decode and authenticate. A tutorial I followed added the code inside the 'if' statement, shown below (also in the code snippet above), to make sure even when a page is reloaded, the localstorage still persists this token:

```
  if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
    setAuthorizationToken(localStorage.jwtToken)
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwt.decode(localStorage.jwtToken)))
}
```

Running the app from a development server that `create-react-app` provides for you works fine. I can reload the page from any url e.g '/', or '/profile', etc and the token is still available. Only when I log out is the token is deleted. 
The problem comes when I run `npm build` to create a production ready single js file, that I then reference in my html file. Reloading the browser from any other url that is not '/' throws an error that 'no token provided' (this is a custom error message from my node server that I want thrown when no token is attached to the request). Which simply means the browser deletes this token when I reload the page. How can I persist this token in production js file much reathe same way dev server does?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using localStorage wrongly.
Actually, to set a key on localStorage, you would do:

```
localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', 'my-token-here')
```

Then, to recover it:

```
localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
```

Localstorage is the right option if you want to persist data even if the browser closes.
Otherwise, if you want the data to get lost, you should use SessionStorage API.

Good luck.

Comment: I set the token as you suggest, and even used your suggestion to recover it, and as I mentioned in the question, in development server that react starts at port 3000, everything is fine..checking the storage tab in the browser, the token is persisted and reloading the pages at any url still works, but when I build the app for production, the browser deletes the token upon reload :(

Comment: really really strange, how about, if you remove everything and test it raw. `import React from 'react' import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' import Router from './routes' localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', 'my-token-here') ReactDOM.render( <Router/> , document.getElementById('root'))` Build it and test. Does it keep my-token-here in your localStorage?

Comment: I have created a new react app using `create-react-app`, which will definitely take some time to set everything up, in the mean time, your code should work..because its also working in my project. This is because when url is at '/', the code at index is the one being executed, but when you navigate to other urls, the code wont run...and so reloading at these other urls, the code to set item is not executed

Comment: Even in this way, it was supposed to work.

what if you try to do it in a common component between your pages?

Comment: I have created a new skeleton app with `create-react-app` and only added 2 routes: '/' and '/profile'. On the dev server, it creates the token and persists it in both urls, but dreadfully refused to work after building the app. It only creates the token in '/' but in '/profile' the browser deletes the token...This is frustrating

Comment: What do you mean by a common component? Isn't that what Provider and connect from react-redux offer? or how would I implement your idea?

Comment: can you share a github repo with this create-react-app? 

im working with a freelance right now (i have used CRA too) and localstorage is working really fine for me.

Comment: if you let me suggest you...there is this package "redux-localstorage", which saves keys from your redux store to localstorage automatically for you, you just have to specify which keys you want to persist.

Comment: I have created the report at this [Github Link](https://github.com/Nahasean94/testing-tokens).
Let me try that module "redux-localstorage" and see if it helps

Comment: I have made few changes to your code:

[index.js](https://gist.github.com/marcelorl/3407910f65c032517f51e657f3706a0e#file-testing-tokens-index-js)
[App.js](https://gist.github.com/marcelorl/7d53c542721a4b2ede32b6af345f7afc#file-testing-tokens-app-js)

Comment: They work perfectly. You might have getting some cache issues. Try force cleaning cache.

Comment: Did you test your code after building it? Coz mine does not seem to work after building

Comment: Yes, I did. "npm run build && npx serve -s build". How are you exactly testing your built files?

Comment: I was taking the build folder and including it inside my node server public folder ..such that I only had one server running. That is where tokens were being deleted. But with the `serve` module, I will have front end server and back end server running. This way the token is persisted but another problem arises...Please check [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/serve/issues/353) i posted on their github repo and see if you can help me. If I crack that issue with cors, my problems are over.